# Best approach to implement background task while app is running

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios4

What is the best approach to implement a task in iOS which is doing his work in an other thread while the app is running?

I would like to implement a Thread that is checking every 10 minutes for updates while the app  is running. Is there such a possibility to implement this? I think I cant implement a thread that has an endless loop because apple will reject the app, right?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely do not need a thread that idles endlessly but I can't imagine Apple rejecting your app for *that* reason: but it's simply not good app design.

I suspect what you really want to do is have a ["`NSTimer`" task](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html) that runs every ten minutes.

There's also the possibility of sending a [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a) message to an object and then having that fire off a separate thread to do the background work.